# Qt Gui Unit Test: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

I managed to write a "Gui Unit Test" using [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial3.html). However, when I compile my code I get this:

```
PASS   : testUnits::initTestCase()
PASS   : testUnits::toUpper()
QFATAL : testUnits::testGui() QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
FAIL!  : testUnits::testGui() Received a fatal error.
Unknown file(0) : failure location
Totals: 2 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
********* Finished testing of testUnits *********
```

why is it giving me: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice ?

Comment: You are probably missing something, make sure you follow every detail of that tutorial you link to. I have not used that unit testing framework, but the `QTEST_MAIN(TestGui)` should be smart enough to create a QApplication instance when testing GUI, unless the whole framework is broken.

Comment: Another thing, are you by any chance using Qt5? Difference between Qt4 and Qt5 is enough to certainly break that unit testing framework, and you need a Qt5 version, if such exists.

Comment: Are you using the QtGui library (i.e. is `QT += gui` in your `.pro`)?

Comment: @hyde: you are right, I missed puting my QApplication before calling my Gui unit test. so, it was looking for the QPaintDevice(i.e.: QEditLine) while there is no QApplication available (see my code in the my own answer). Thanks again for mentioning the Qt4 and Qt5 difference problem, I will keep it in mind because I am working on two Qts one is Qt4 and the other is Qt5

Comment: @cmannett85: no I am not, but if I have to, why then my code is working. even before, I can assure you that my unit test was working fine because it gives me a "fail" output as a result. my problem was why is it failing ?. But since you mention it, what `QT += gui` do exactly ?

Comment: From the `QTEST_MAIN(TestClass)` docs: "If QT_GUI_LIB is defined, the application object will be a QApplication, otherwise it will be a QCoreApplication. If qmake is used and the configuration includes QT += gui, then QT_GUI_LIB will be defined automatically".  It's usually defined automatically but if you forcibly removed it (`QT -= gui`), then there would be no way to create a `QPaintDevice`.

Answer (score 2):

it works now, here is my Gui unit test function definition:

```
void testUnits::testGui(){
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    QTest::keyClicks(&lineEdit,"hellow world");
    QCOMPARE(lineEdit.text(), QString("hello world"));
}
```

and here is how my main() looked like before fixing the problem :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    testUnits testString;
    QTest::qExec(&testString, argc, argv);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

So, when I compile the code, it execute the unit test before constructing the QApplication.

Therefore I put my QTest::qExec() after QApplication and now it works and the main() looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    testUnits testString;
    QTest::qExec(&testString, argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: By unwrapping the QTEST_MAIN macro like this, I was able to run code BEFORE QApplication was instanciated which is a requirement if you want to set the attribute Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts on the app object. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to not define your own `main` manually. All of the test logic, including the required preconditions, shall be made within the test object (the `QObject` subclass with the `test*` slots) itself. See the [QTestLib manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html#creating-a-test) for details.

If you do this, then simply using the `QTEST_MAIN` will do the right thing and save you some time.

Comment: The problem with this is that isn't nicely scalable, because you can't separate out grouped tests into their own headers - everything has to be a part of the same test object. My personal project has relatively poor unit test coverage, but trying to work with a single header with hundreds of well doxygened unit tests is a huge pain (even if you can separate out the source files), I can't imagine how bad it would be thousands of tests...

Comment: I'm not familiar with your use case, but the obvious answer is to split the tests into multiple classes (and thus also multiple standalone executables). QTestLib supports the ``make check`` target by default.